# How can I generate correlated timeseries made up of 0s and 1s?

Tags: time-series, simulation, markov-process

I want to generate series of 0s and 1s that exhibit some clustering. By this I mean that 1s and 0s should occur together. So I envisage series of 0s and 1s that will exhibit similar clustering of these elements, and not just random series of 0s and 1s.

In essence, for a single time series, I would go about that by thresholding a Markov chain with a 2x2 transition matrix, with some stochastic added on to it. Now, I'm not too certain on how to do this, but since I would like to produce several of these series, I was wondering whether there's something straightforward that I have missed.

I plan to use these series to simulate data availability (0 or 1) in a data acquisition system and to do some Monte Carlo simulations of how this affects what we can do with the data.

In order for the above simulations to be realistic, I would like to fit real observations to this model, so that the simulated time series share temporal correlation with the data. I would initially do this by calculating lag autocorrelations of both series and tweaking model parameters until I get something that resembles my observations, but unsure whether this is the best way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A standard method is to begin by generating an autocorrelated Gaussian process $z_i$.  (It doesn't have to be Gaussian, but such processes are easy to generate.)  Take the logistic (inverse logit) of the values, producing a series of numbers $p_i = 1/\left(1 + \exp(-z_i)\right)$ in the interval $(0,1)$.  Independently draw values from Bernoulli($p_i$) distributions to create a series of $0$ and $1$ values.  Clustering will tend to occur with positive autocorrelation.

As a bonus, this procedure allows you to perform two stages of simulation: you can fix the underlying realization of the Gaussian process and iterate the second stage of Bernoulli draws.  Or you can generate a separate realization of the Gaussian process each time.

There are probably R packages to do all this directly.  The `geoRGLM` package performs this simulation in two dimensions (using a Matern autocorrelation function, which includes exponential and Gaussian autocorrelations as special cases); you could simulate along a straight line (or $1$ by $n$ grid) to obtain a time series.

Comment: Why logistic over the inverse cdf? Numerical reasons?

Comment: OK, this is quite neat. I've put together some python code to do this here: http://pastebin.com/y5SyzuVu

Comment: @JMS This is just a binomial GLM with logit link.

Comment: Or you could just threshold the process $(z_i)$. The relationship between the autocorrelation of $(z_i)$ and that of the binary thresholded process is a little more direct.

Comment: @JMS, I think you meant cdf, not inverse cdf. :)

Comment: @cardinal Sure did :) @whuber Yeah, was just wondering if the logit was preferred over the probit for any particular reason. It'd give roughly @cardinal's suggestion, where the probability is $p=\Phi(\gamma)$ for the threshold $\gamma$. I don't suppose it matters much.

Comment: @cardinal In the end, I implemented your solution. As you mention, it's simpler to specify the fraction of 0s or 1s in the simulated time series this way.

Comment: @Jose In your application that's a good simple solution, because you do not have a particular model in mind, nor do you aim to use the model for estimation, prediction, or inference: all you need are simulations that exhibit some form of correlation.  In general, though, the GLM approach has a nice tractable theory, good likelihood estimators, and an existing code base, all of which make it an attractive solution.

Comment: You could also just threshold the autocorrelated Gaussian variables at any number (e.g. 0) to produce autocorrelated binary data.

Comment: @Macro I believe that's exactly @cardinal's solution.

Comment: @whuber OK, the likelihood function has got me hooked now :) I've expanded my question to include how to fit the model to observations.

Comment: @Jose Diggle & Ribeiro (*Model-Based Geostatistics*, 2007) say likelihood methods are "hampered by computational difficulties."  They describe three solutions.  (1) MCMC.  (2) "Hierarchical likelihood" (Lee & Nelder).  (3) GEE.  D&R provide likelihood estimation, as well as simulation, in their `geoR` package.